# How to share tensorflow weights with other users

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

is it possible to share tensorflow checkpoint files with other users (plattform & CPU/GPU independet)? I had shared a [tensorflow implementation of the DeconvNet](https://github.com/fabianbormann/Tensorflow-DeconvNet-Segmentation) and now I want to provide the trained weights. Can I simply upload the saved model or is there another tf way? I'm asking because I read a tutorial were the weights were stored using `numpy.savetxt` and then restored during the weight initalization. But this method was used for the MNIST example which uses a very small net..

Thanks!

Comment: You could save metagraph + provide code to restore and run your model -- https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/meta_graph/

Comment: Ah ok cool! Thank you! If you could post that comment as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save metagraph + provide code to restore and run your model -- 
http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/meta_graph

One downside of this is that it doesn't provide annotations of which tensors to feed/fetch, so you need to provide some code showing how to use it.

`SavedModel` is the next iteration of TensorFlow checkpoint format that takes care of that, but it doesn't have much documentation yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use [pickle, in binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL), to dump and load big numpy matrix and it works quite well.

Comment: So you would recommend a numpy way over tensorflow checkpoint files? Or do you mean save/load big matrices in general?

Comment: I mean save/load big matrices in general.